# angular multiple ng-repeat multiple filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an multiple ng-repeat list with multiple filters.

I use (ex:A.value) if (ex:B.value) , but I want to with multiple filters.

I want to multiple filters recommend_search and skill_search and language_search ,

then Search results is want to change the whole (html div class="panel")

now recommend_search filters is ok, but skill_search and language_search filters is only span range(html span id="language" and span id="skill")

How can I do multiple filters search results to change the whole(html div class="panel")?

angular.js

```
$scope.recommend=[];
  $http.get('/recommend/ajax').success(function (data, status) {
     $scope.recommend = data;
  });
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="recommendCtrl">
<!-- search -->
<div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="recommend search" ng-model="recommend_search.name">
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="skill search" ng-model="skill_search.skill_name">
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="language search" ng-model="language_search.languagelv_name">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- recommend -->
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="(key, value) in recommend.recommend  | orderBy:'-id' | filter:recommend_search">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- content -->
        <div class="panel-content">
                <label class="ahr-label_bs">
                    @{{ value.family_name}}@{{value.surname}}
                    <span ng-if="value.sex == 1">♂</span>
                    <span ng-if="value.sex == 0">♀</span>
                </label>
                <span>@{{value.name}}</span>
                <!-- skill -->
                <label class="label-gray">skill</label>
                <span id="skill" ng-repeat="skill in recommend.personnels_skill  | filter:skill_search" ng-if="value.personnels_id == skill.personnels_id">
                              @{{skill.skill_name}}、
                            </span></p>
                <!-- language -->
                <label class="label-gray">language</label>
                <span id="language" ng-repeat="language in recommend.languagelvs  | filter:language_search" ng-if="value.personnels_id == language.personnels_id">
                              @{{language.languagelv_name}}、
                </span>

                <label class="label-gray">country</label><span>@{{ value.country }}</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may chain filters.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="(key, value) in recommend.recommend  | orderBy:'-id' | filter:recommendSearch | filter:anotherFilter | filter: oneMoreFilter">
```

Comment: `<span class="input-group-btn">



  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="recommend search" ng-model="recommend_search.name">

</span>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="skill search" ng-model="anotherFilter.personnels_skill.skill_name">
</span>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="language search" ng-model="oneMoreFilter.languagelvs.languagelv_name">
</span>`